# How to Reduce Mysql Size After Dropping Table

Tags: mysql

I dropped a corrupted table with large size to reduce the server size.

But the server size still the same!

I entered the MYSQL location in my server and found a .ARN file with the name of the dropped table with 28GB size.

I tried to optimize the table after dropping it, but sure its not exist

Is it safe to remove .ARN file through the command line ?

Or what can I do to free this 28GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have leftover some temporary file of the ARCHIVE engine: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html

This engine is barely supported, and I would not be surprised that is has bugs. Assuming there is no .arz file, and that no client is accesing it, it should be safe to drop. One recommendation I always follow is to rename or backup any db-related file before removing it. That will give you an extra guarantee in the worst case possible.

As an extra comment- avoid archive engine at all costs- if you need a compressed table you can use InnoDB, TokuDB or RocksDB.

Comment: yes it have no .ARZ or .frm files, I only found just the .ARN for the dropped table with 28G
Thanks ..  I will get a backup first